# NSObject class working

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nsobject

I am using `NSObject` class in my project and I want to use network indicator in `NSObject` class like when I call any function of that class network indication starts and once code comes out from class, network indicator stops.

For starting network indicator, I am using `initialize()` function as:

```
override class func initialize () {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
}
```

Now I want to know in which function, I stop network indicator. Basically which function call at last in `NSObject` class?

Comment: Do you have any idea about completion handler(return back methods)..? i think it can be help full for you

Comment: Try to put it in deInit()

Comment: deinit() is not working for me @VishalSonawane

Comment: @Katty  NO. can you please post an example or link for that. btw thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably implement a `-dealloc` method, which is invoked only when the object is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If the `deinit( )` method is not working it means that you are not deallocating the object properly, you may have a memory leak there(only if you're intetionally make it work deallocating the object).

Another approach would be a `defer {}` implementation in the methods that would set the indicator to true.

```
func myMethod(){
    defer{
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
    }
}
```

If you're using `func initialize()` you probably can use `func finalize()`

```
override class func finalize () {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
}
```

Comment: if I use this then i have to call this function in every other functions and i don't want to do that.

Comment: @NavjotSingh can you try `finalize()` ?

Comment: i already tried before asking this question but it doesn't works.